# Python how to release the memory for class object after processing it?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, object, memory

I use **None keyword to delete a class object.**

```
 class demo:
   class members

 obj= demo()
 some processing
 obj=None
```

By using **None**,will the memory be released?

I found that **del** can also be used to delete a class object.Or I should use

```
   del obj
```

to release the memory?

What is the difference between using **del and None** in deleting a class object and **releasing the memory or invoking garbage collection**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python objects are released when there are no more references to the object.

Rebinding `obj` to `None` would decrease the reference count to the object, and so would `del obj`. In *both cases*, the instance would be cleared if `obj` was the last reference to it.

The difference then is how you can use `obj` afterwards. Rebinding retains the variable (it is now bound to `None`), `del` removes it altogether and you'd get a `NameError`. What you pick is your choice, it won't have influence on how the instance is cleared from memory.