# How to free memory of COM objects in Outlook, which runs out of memory when processing several thousand emails?

Tags: python, outlook, com, win32com, mapi

I have a Python script that gets the email message IDs of all the emails in the inbox folder.
However, Outlook throws an out-of-memory exception when it reaches several thousand emails.

Exception:

```
Printing emails...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "print_emails.py", line 53, in main
    print_emails()
  File "print_emails.py", line 43, in print_emails
    primary_emails, primary_email_ids = get_emails_and_ids(primary_source_folder)
  File "print_emails.py", line 29, in get_emails_and_ids
    property_accessor = item.PropertyAccessor
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 474, in __getattr__
    return self._ApplyTypes_(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 467, in _ApplyTypes_
    self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Out of memory or system resources. Close some windows or programs and try again.', None, 0, -2147024882), None)

Press enter to exit...
```

I have tried two different methods: iterating once (`get_emails_and_ids`) and twice (`get_emails` and `get_email_ids`).

It seems to be related to getting the `PropertyAccessor` several thousand times. If I just get emails using `get_emails`, it runs fine with 38,000 emails, but when I start getting the IDs using `PropertyAccessor` thousands of times, that is when it runs out of memory. Do I have to release the old property accessors?

Install:

```
pip install -U pypiwin32
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from typing import Any, List, Tuple, Set

import traceback
import win32com.client

PidTagInternetMessageId = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F"

primary_account_email = "user@domain.tld"
primary_source_folder_name = "Inbox"


def get_emails(folder) -> List:
    return [item for item in folder.Items if "_MailItem" in str(type(item))]


def get_email_ids(emails) -> Set[str]:
    return {email_id for email in emails if len(email_id := email.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PidTagInternetMessageId)) > 0}


def get_emails_and_ids(folder) -> Tuple[List, Set[str]]:
    emails = []
    email_ids = set()

    for item in folder.Items:
        if "_MailItem" in str(type(item)):
            emails.append(item)
            property_accessor = item.PropertyAccessor
            email_id = property_accessor.GetProperty(PidTagInternetMessageId)
            email_ids.add(email_id)

    return emails, email_ids


def print_emails() -> None:
    outlook = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
    namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    primary_account = namespace.Folders[primary_account_email]
    primary_folders = primary_account.Folders
    primary_source_folder = primary_folders[primary_source_folder_name]
    primary_emails, primary_email_ids = get_emails_and_ids(primary_source_folder)
    # primary_emails = get_emails(primary_source_folder)
    # primary_email_ids = get_email_ids(primary_emails)

    print(primary_email_ids)


def main(*args: Tuple[Any, ...]) -> None:
    try:
        print(f"Printing emails...")
        print_emails()
        print()
        print("Done.")
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
    print()

    print("Press enter to exit...")
    input()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: In C#, one would ensure all COM objects are manually disposed. That would in turn trigger the RCW’s COM+ ref-count decr. Does the Python bridge have/support similar? Outlook uses aggressive caching and I vaguely recall having to force-release certain COM objects. That was also a decade ago :rolls eyes:

Comment: @user2864740 That's what I am trying to figure out how to do in Python. [Set the variable to `None`, `del` the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299106/python-how-to-release-the-memory-for-class-object-after-processing-it/29299176#29299176), or [use `gc.collect()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python/1316793#1316793)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to not store all the emails ([MailItem objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem)) in a list. If I need emails in a list, when I process the email, I should `list.pop()` or remove it right away from the list. Using the `PropertyAccessor` and keeping the email in the list causes Outlook to keep the objects in memory and causes Outlook to run out of memory.

I got rid of the `get_emails` and `get_emails_and_ids` functions and re-wrote the `get_email_ids` function to store only the email message IDs but not store the email objects in a list:

```
def get_email_ids(folder) -> Tuple[Set[str], int]:
    email_ids = set()

    items = folder.Items
    i = 0
    for item in items:
        if "_MailItem" in str(type(item)):
            i += 1

            property_accessor = item.PropertyAccessor
            email_id = property_accessor.GetProperty(PidTagInternetMessageId)
            if len(email_id) > 0:
                email_ids.add(email_id)

            if i % 500 == 0:
                print(f"    Retrieved {i} email IDs.")

    return email_ids, i
```

My other script that I wrote is a lot faster now and takes at least 10 minutes. Before, it used to process a couple emails per second and take hours.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the "`for`" loop with a loop from 1 to Items.Count (retrieve an item using Items(i)) - not sure about Python, but in other languages "`foreach`" loops tend to hold all items of the collection referenced until the loop exits.

Comment: I was holding all the emails ([MailItem objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem)) in a list. I think that was the problem. Thanks.